# having command in sql

Tags: sql

When I write this SQL command:

```
SELECT Year,
       Count(Book_Id)
FROM   Books
WHERE  Pages > 200
GROUP  BY Year
HAVING Avg(Pages) > 400
```

The `"HAVING AVG(Pages) > 400"` - will this calculate the pages average of all books in the year, or only books where pages are more then 200?

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` clause filters the rows and gives you only books with Pages >200 , so the `HAVING` clause will be applied only for these books.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps show the `logical processing order` for a `SELECT` statement. This order determines when the objects defined in one step are made available to the **clauses in subsequent steps**.

**Note** : The actual physical execution of the statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this list

```
 1. FROM
 2. ON
 3. JOIN
 4. WHERE
 5. GROUP BY
 6. HAVING
 7. SELECT
 8. DISTINCT
 9. ORDER BY
 10. TOP
```

So First the `Where Clause` is applied which will filter with books with **pages more then 200** then then `having clause` is applied to
only books that there **pages are more then 200**

Check this **[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)** for more info if you are using `SQL SERVER`

Comment: This is not how a query is *executed*.  It is how a query is *compiled*.  This is the logical interpretation of the query.